# loopback model hooks not working

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I am currently working on an appointment booking app using loopback, below is my appointment.js from the common/model directory

```
module.exports = function(Appointment) {


  Appointment.afterCreate = function (next) {
      //TODO add appointment details should not be hardcoded get users email here
      var emailService = require('../../common/services/email.server.service');
      emailService.sendUserEmail('dummy@dummy.com');
      next();
  };

  Appointment.beforeUpdate = function(next) {
      var emailService = require('../../common/services/email.server.service');
      if(this.appointmentStatus === 'waiting_agent'){
          console.log(this.appointmentStatus);
      } else if(this.appointmentStatus === 'waiting_user'){
          console.log(this.appointmentStatus);
      } else {
          console.log(this.appointmentStatus);
      }

      emailService.sendUserEmail('dummy@dummy.com');

      next();

  };
};
```

The afterCreate function works well and sends out an email, however afterUpdate/beforeUpdate doesnt work, I am using Angular as front end and using Angular loopback to generate services, and below is the update function :

```
function updateAppointment(listingId,newAppointmentInfo,status){
    Appointment.updateAll(
        {
            where:
            {
                listingId : listingId
            }
        },
        {
            "appointmentDate": newAppointmentInfo.selectedDate,
            "appointmentTime" : newAppointmentInfo.selectedTime,
            "appointmentStatus" : status
        },
        function (appointment){
            console.log(appointment);
        },
        function (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    )
}
```

Is it because I am calling the /Appointment/update api rather then UPDATE on /Appointment ?

Answer (score 1):

Model hooks are being deprecated in favor of operation and per-method hooks. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Operation+hooks

For more information, see the last comment in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/366

Answer (score 0):

Loopback has some issues with model hooks triggering.
See issue https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/202

Comment: Although the linked information might provide valuable information, would be a lot more helpful, for the OP and others searching for the same issue, if you could describe what are these "some issues" and how do you believe they relate to the problem faced.